# How to connect android application to sql server 2012 using library jTDS JDBC Driver

Tags: java, android, sql-server, jdbc

I am a new member, android developer. When i use library jTDS JDBC Driver (jtds-1.2.7) to make a connection to sql server, I recieve this error:

```
    unknown server host name unable to resolve host "127.0.0.0.1\sqlexpress": No address associated with hostname
```

Here is the source code:

```
Connection connection ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
connection=CONN("sa", "abc123", "SqlForAndroid", "127.0.0.1\\sqlexpress:1433");
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private Connection CONN(String _user, String _pass, String _DB, String _server )
{
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
Connection conn = null;
String ConnURL = null;
try {

    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + _server + ";"+"databaseName=" + _DB + ";user=" + _user + ";password=" + _pass +";";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);        
} catch (SQLException se) {
    Log.e("ERRO",se.getMessage());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("ERRO",e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ERRO",e.getMessage());
}

return conn;
```

}

I need a solution...

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to connect to 127.0.0.1.  That's yourself.  I doubt that the db is on your phone, since it isn't SQLite.  Fix the IP address.

As an aside-  connecting directly via mobile to a db is a bad idea from a security perspective.  It requires you to allow any IP to connect to your db.  A better way to do it is to put a webservice in between, and then only allow that PC to connect directly to the db.  It makes it more difficult to gain access to your data.

Comment: thank you so much! i have found out a solution. that is change ip address